# MODX revo Wayfinder Not Showing

Tags: menu, header, modx

I'm working with Wayfinder, testing it out to see how it works but for some reason, it's not working and by that I mean that I place the code where it should be and it doesn't output anything at all, I get a blank menu section on my header.

I've been learning form this guide http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2011/02/21/modx-revolution-for-complete-beginners-part-8-using-wayfinder-to-create-menus/

I've followed the instructions on this hands-on video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eabBx-KUHjk

as well as the documentation on the wiki.

I placed this on the header to test how the menu loads but nothing happened.

```
<!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->
<nav>
[[!Wayfinder? &startid='0']]
</nav>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->
```

The output is nothing at all. The "Hide From Menus" option is unchecked so I'm rather clueless as of why nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. It seems it's case sensitive and &startid should be &startId

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId='0']]
```

although I think it's a little odd that if I have more items under the same tree and I use &startid (lowercase) it lists everything but the root document but if I use it with capital "I" then it lists everything starting from the root.

In any case, it's working now.